# Change Davinci Resolve Fusion timeline to 0

Tags: davinci-resolve, timecode, fusion

I have a long clip that I've cut down and now I am making changes in fusion. The timeline starts at the specific frame I cut it from (from my example, frames 984-1119). I Want the timeline to start at 0 frames instead of 984 for this specific clip so that my animated presets can easily work on it.

I want fusion to act as if the clip I cut is its own independent clip so that the timeline could start from 0.

Is this possible? Or is there an alternative way to get the same result?

[image: Picture of my timeline in fusion.]